# Spotfire Calendar Filter

Tags: spotfire

Is there a way I can use calendar filter in Spotfire? I am aware of the range filter, but I want the user to only be able to select one date from a range of dates coming from a table.

Answer (score 6):

it's a little bit advanced and requires some scripting (although code is provided), but a date picker can be used:

http://spotfired.blogspot.ch/2014/05/popup-calendar-webplayer-compatible.html

the result is something like this:

[image: date picker]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is two years old but I still came across this post and I figured someone else will too.

To get the calendar to filter follow these steps:

- Edit the Text Area
- Click "Insert Filter"
- Click the column from your data that contains dates
- Click "Ok"

Once you save, you will have a slider in the text box and two calendars where dates can be picked or you can utilize the slider.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Spotfire has a calendar date picker built into the filter and data panels (but it is part of the range slider).

You can also insert this filter into a text area if you want a more custom user interface. See below:

[Calendar date picker in Spotfire text area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBkhy.jpg)

Comment: How do you enable the calendar. It is not showing up for me.