# TIBCO spotfire date filter control - apply greater than date expression on date filter control

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I am a sportfire beginner and just learned to customize Date filter using below URL,

> [Spotfire Calendar Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910896/spotfire-calendar-filter/39797020#39797020)

Just want to filter and display report data (report mapping column : LastModifiedDate) greater than date based on this filter date selected value.

Please help.

Comment: If you add the filter to your text area then adjust the start date, or minimum date this will work.

Comment: Thank you. It's a silly question. Am not sure where to configure. Can you please add reference screenshot / script.

Comment: I provided you instructions below. Let me know if that works out

Answer (score 0):

1. From the main tool bar: `Insert > New Text Area`
2. From the text area: `Right Click > Edit Text Area`
3. Then, Click the `Insert Filter` button. If you don't see it, click the `>>` button on the top right to see all of your options.
4. Select the column which contains your dates. Click Ok.
5. From the text area: `Right Click > Un-select Edit Text Area`

[Tibco's Documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/text/text_how_to_use_the_text_area.htm) lists in detail how to accomplish most everything you need. Be sure to keep this reference handy. About 3/4 of the way down on this specific page you'll see instructions on how to do what I listed above.

Answer (score -1):

I added 2 Date text filters on the text Area.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3uaP.png)

As you can see there is one filter text for the start date and one for end date.
Exist any possibility to use then as a range filter because they only filter matching equal date. I want to use them as minimum(start date) and maximum date(end date).
Example:
Text filter 1 : 10/10/2000
Text filter 2 : 09/09/2015
Result : all records between the 2 dates.